# What function should i used to get these buttons to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

$ <button id="button1">Grow</button> 
$ <button id="button2">Blue</button> 
$ <button id="button3">Fade</button> 
$ <button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!!

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (this.id == 'button1') {
    $('#box').css('transform', 'scale(1.2)');
  } else if (this.id == 'button2') {
    $('#box').css('background', 'blue');
  } else if (this.id == 'button3') {
    $('#box').css('opacity', '0.2');
  } else {
    $('#box').css('background', 'orange');
    $('#box').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
    $('#box').css('opacity', '1');
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" $ src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

$ <button id="button1">Grow</button> $ <button id="button2">Blue</button> $ <button id="button3">Fade</button> $ <button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much this really helped much appreciated man.

Comment: please feel free to accept the answer if the post is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a class for each style and use the switch statement for each button - referencing its data attribute.

```js
var box = $('#box');

$('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4').click(function(){  
  var id = $(this).data("val");
  switch (id) {
      case 1:
          box.addClass('grow');
          break;
      case 2:
          box.addClass('blue');
          break;
      case 3:
          box.addClass('fade');
          break;
      default:
          box.removeClass();
      }
  })
```

```css
.blue {
    background-color: blue !important;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.grow {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="b1" data-val="1">Grow</button>
<button id="b2" data-val="2">Blue</button>
<button id="b3" data-val="3">Fade</button>
<button id="b4" data-val="4">Reset</button>
```